# Lambdas broken with gradle version 3.2.1

Tags: android, gradle

after i updated gradle version from 3.2.0 to version 3.2.1
all my lambda expressions are broken:

error: cannot find symbol method metafactory(Lookup,String,MethodType,MethodType,MethodHandle,MethodType)

my module-level build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xyz.test.lambdatest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}
```

app-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

can anyone tell me why it works with gradle 3.2.0 but not with gradle 3.2.1?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: No i have not..

Comment: For those looking for solution - in my case the files were missing from my sdk. I had to reinsatll via sdk manager in android studio.